# Unable to use keyboard buttons on android emulator

Tags: android, eclipse, android-edittext

Now i created one android project which consist of one edit text box,here my problem is,after get running of my project when i am trying to type some text on the edit text box of an emulator through keyboard, its not supporting but, qwerty touch key board is supporting when i am clicking the edit text box using cursor.Is there any things to do with setting option?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: And are you running ADT 20? (Sorry, I should have asked this before. ><)

Comment: @Eric yes i am running ADT 20

Answer (score 8, accepted):

go to the **AVD> your target >edit>hardware >new>keyboard support>yes**

Answer (score 3):

There is some kind of bug (or a messed-up feature) in ADT 20 that causes this issue. For some reason, it removes the interaction via physical keyboard, and you must re-add it yourself.

I found the trick below from someone who uses a Mac, however I checked it with my Windows 7 machine and the settings process *should* be the same.

1. First, close your emulator and open the AVD Manager (you can do this through `Eclipse -> Window` if in Eclipse; otherwise it should be in your SDK folder).
2. You need to pick the emulator you are using (the one you want to fix), then click `Edit...`. Under `Hardware:`, select `New...`, then search the dropdown and find `Keyboard Support`, and hit `OK`.
3. Next, select `Keyboard support` from the `Hardware:` section, then click (or maybe double-click) the `Value` column, and change it to `yes`.
4. Lastly, click `Edit AVD` to complete the process.

You should click `Edit...` again, and verify that `Keyboard support` is still set to `yes`. If it is, start your emulator, and you should be good to go!